# Can さ be added to nouns?

Tags: grammar

I want to equate the quality of something to an apple. (Bare with me, just using a random noun to make the desired construct clearer.) But instead of going around it and saying something like "it looks like an apple" or "has apple-like qualities", I want to just go ahead and say "appleness", like "Your appleness is amazing". Evidently this can't be done in valid English, but is there a way to do this in valid Japanese?

Slightly better example: "Your childishness is annoying." If don't want to say 'childishness' and instead want to specify the exact level of referenced age, say grade-schooler: "Your grade-schooler-ness is annoying." Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to macraf's answer, らしさ and っぽさ are slightly different, and not always interchangeable.

**らしさ** suggests an integral set of qualities or appearance, and is generally approving of those qualities.

**っぽさ** is much more vague, and can be used in a dismissive way.

Although you can say either りんごらしさのある味 or りんごっぽさのある味 to praise a flavor, only 〜っぽさ can be used to criticize a flavor. So if you're calling out someone's annoying grade-schooler-like behavior, that would be 小学生っぽさ and not 小学生らしさ.

The two need to be distinguished carefully with some nouns like 子供, because 子供らしさ is a good thing and 子供っぽさ is a usually a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, mirka makes a good point here. This may be similar to usage in English: 女らしい = "womanly", as a positive. 女っぽい = "womanish" as a possibly bad thing. Same for 男らしい "manly" and 男っぽい "mannish".

Answer (score 4):

Not directly as 〜さ makes a noun out of an adjective.

You can first make an adjective out of a noun by adding 〜らしい and then make it a noun again by changing to 〜らしさ.

In fact you can even find the word "appleness" アップルらしさ used/defined in 日経新聞 [article](http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXZZO76838990Z00C14A9000000/), so not a bad example at all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the added explanation. I wish I could +10 for coming across アップルらしさ. If only they were talking about actual apples so that I could find out what my example really meant...

Comment: @idlackage You can find examples of りんごらしさ or りんごっぽさ on the web, although they aren't particularly common! http://ameblo.jp/art-sketch-cafe/entry-10826838584.html - http://club.coneco.net/user/34725/review/75987/ - http://ptakato.com/banapple/

Comment: Afraid you are not reading that article correctly.  「アップルらしさ」 is about the company Apple, not about an apple or apples as a fruit, which is what OP is talking about .

Comment: Would りんごらしさ work?